# How to maintain hover state even when mouseout of main drop down link

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a working pure css dropdown menu

html;

```
<ul id=nav>
<li><a href="">Main Link 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 1 Sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 1 Sub Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 1 Sub Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 1 Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="">Main Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Main Link 3</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 3 Sub Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 3 Sub Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 3 Sub Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Main Link 3 Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="">Main Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Pls view the complete form below as I can't post all the css code here;

http://jsfiddle.net/hF3dm/

My problem is when you hover the mail link and proceed to the sub links, the hover state for the main link disappears. How do I keep the hover state of the main link active whilst hovering over the sub links???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best thing to do is to put the hover state for the main link on the 'li' rather than the 'a' tag.

```
ul#nav li:hover {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: thanx Billy! That was much simpler than I thought! I have updated the jfiddle thanx to you! :)

Comment: No probs. Was a eureka moment when I figured this one out myself years ago.

Answer (score 2):

i've just added the:

```
#nav li:hover { background-color: #a32a31; color: #fff; }
```

to your example (at the bottom of the css) and seems to do what you need now

example at http://jsfiddle.net/hF3dm/6/